# Connect to socket leaves connections in TIME_WAIT states

Tags: c, sockets

I'm attempting to resolve a hostname and then open / close a socket with the host.

The code below works fine. The problem I have is the connections don't seem to be closed correctly. I'm left with a pile of TIME_WAITS:

```
tcp        0      0 192.168.142.139:44475   172.217.23.14:443       TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 192.168.142.139:44362   45.79.5.162:80          TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 192.168.142.139:44373   45.79.5.162:80          TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 192.168.142.139:44461   172.217.23.14:443       TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 192.168.142.139:44468   172.217.23.14:443       TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 192.168.142.139:44472   172.217.23.14:443       TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 192.168.142.139:44474   172.217.23.14:443       TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 192.168.142.139:44459   172.217.23.14:443       TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 192.168.142.139:44470   172.217.23.14:443       TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 192.168.142.139:44463   172.217.23.14:443       TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 192.168.142.139:44464   172.217.23.14:443       TIME_WAIT
```

I don't particularly need to send anything specific to the host, it's more of a general internet check. I've also tried the same using a non-blocking connection followed by a select instead. Same result.

```
  int port = 443;
  char *hostname = "google.com";

  int open_socket(char *ip)
  {
    int error = 0; // Socket error
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    short int sock = -1;
    fd_set fdset;
    struct timeval tv;
    int so_keepalive = 0;

    sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (sock < 0)
      return 150;

    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
    address.sin_port = htons(port);
    /* address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; */

    FD_ZERO(&fdset);
    FD_SET(sock, &fdset);
    tv.tv_sec =  3;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    int yes = 1;
    // setsockopt(sock,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,&yes,sizeof(int));
    // setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&tv, sizeof(struct timeval));
    setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (char *)&tv, sizeof(struct timeval));
    setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &so_keepalive, sizeof(so_keepalive));

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&address , sizeof(address)) < 0)
      error = 150;

    if (error == 0) {
      char *message = "HELLO";
      if (send(sock , message , strlen(message) , 0) < 0)
        error = 180;

      char server_reply[2000];
      if( recv(sock, server_reply , 2000 , 0) < 0)
        error = 190;
    }

    /* shutdown(sock, SHUT_RDWR); */
    close(sock);
    return error;
  }

  int connection_check()
  {
    struct addrinfo *result;
    struct in_addr addr;

    int error;

    error = getaddrinfo(hostname, NULL, NULL, &result);
    if (error != 0)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "DNS Lookup Failed: %s\n", gai_strerror(error));
      return 100;
    }

    addr.s_addr = ((struct sockaddr_in *)(result->ai_addr))->sin_addr.s_addr;
    printf("\nUsing %s for internet check\n", inet_ntoa(addr));
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    return(open_socket(inet_ntoa(addr)));
  }
```

Could someone suggest how I should handle this correctly.

Comment: You are handling this correctly: or at least there is no problem here to solve. The TIME_WAIT state is a normal part of TCP. It lasts a couple of minutes.

Comment: Ok, I was generally concerned that I wasn't closing something properly. I'll ignore and continue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> TCP requires that the endpoint that closes a connection blocks further
>   connections on the same host/port pair until there are no packets from
>   that connection remaining in the network.
>
> To temporarily block connections, one endpoint keeps a copy of the TCP
>   control block (TCB) indicating that the connection has been terminated
>   recently. Such a connection is in the TIME-WAIT state. Connections in
>   TIME-WAIT are moved to CLOSED and their TCB discarded after enough
>   time has passed that all packets from the same connection have left
>   the network. Packets leave the network by arrive at one of the
>   endpoints and being rejected, or arriving with an expired time-to-live
>   (TTL) field at a router and being deleted.

http://www.isi.edu/touch/pubs/infocomm99/infocomm99-web/

Comment: Is this an answer?.

Comment: If it helps you, it is, if not, it isn't ;)